# "Return" to a previous task when implementing menu in console app

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm pretty new to developing and `C#` and, as part of my `C#` class (in school), I have a task to submit.

The task is to make a "TV" in console app, which means I need to make few "frames"/"scenes" with ASCII art with some TV channels, like Disney or news.

And I managed to do it. But my problem is how do I return back to the main menu. I know it sounds confusing so I will try to explain the way my program works.

When you start the program you will receive this:

please choose a channel, by picking its number
            1) ESPN
            2) News
            3) netflix
            4) youtube
            5) disney
            6) tv options

and, if the user writes down 1-6, he will get linked to a different "frame". So, for example, if I chose 5, I would get a new page with some ASCII arts about the Disney channel. I did this fine by using if statements.

But my problem is, how do I make a "return to menu" feature? Like, what if the user wants to come back to the menu (after getting linked into a channel) so they can watch a different channel?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a version of your code as a [repro].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to run a function that displays the options the user can enter and send them back to the function that starts the whole channel picking process over again. Without code examples its hard to give you an exact solution to this, but heres the basic setup:

```
private void ChannelPicker()
{
    //Your previous code here
    ReturnOption();
}

private void ReturnOption()
{
    //Run code to display the options and take user input
    //if the user input == the option you want to set to return run: 
    if (userInput == optionYouSet) ChannelPicker();
}
```

Comment: Why would you keep on recursing? Wha you want is a loop in which you ask the user what to watch. If they want out, break out of the loop. Otherwise show what they ask for.